# Connect from Spring boot app running on Google Cloud Run to a Cloudsql without GCP starter

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, cloud-sql-proxy

I have a Spring boot app running on Google Cloud Run, and I want to connect to a postgres instance running on Google Cloudsql. I am able to connect using Spring Cloud GCP starter project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But I don't want to add this dependency.

I was able to connect from my local app by using using the postgressql plugin and specifying `spring.datasource.url=***` after creating a Cloud proxy.

But when I tried doing the same from cloud run after using `gcloud beta run deploy --add-cloudsql-instances <INSTANCE-ID>` it doesn't work. According to https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connect-cloudsql, `--add-cloudsql-instances` automatically creates a Cloud proxy. So why doesn't it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because Java doesn't support Unix domain sockets. The Spring Cloud GCP circumvents this by using the [Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory).

You can use the Socket Factory directly by adding it your your pom (and updating your URL as specified in the README).

Comment: I already tried doing that, but it didn't work. This is what my application.properties looked like when using the Socket Factory 

`spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=${CLOUDSQL_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://google/${DB}?cloudSqlInstance=${DB_INSTANCE}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=${CLOUDSQL_USERNAME}&password=${CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD}`

Comment: Yes, this should be the answer, but I didn't get this to work either. I am using `DriverManagerDataSource`.